# Cost of SharePoint Licenses

Tags: installation, 2007, licensing

I'm trying to get an understanding of how much it would cost to implement MOSS 2007.

I'm budgetting for an entry level server (around $7k) and using our existing SQL SAN so it is the actual SP licencing model that I am looking for.

To start we would be looking at around 50 users, but this could grow to 450-500 within 12-18 months.

How does the licencing work and what are the costs associated with it?

Would you recommend anything different in terms of the hardware set up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SharePoint licensing is almost a black art.  You can get an idea of the list prices but things vary depending on how many people, who you buy it from, and how it is licensed.

Here is a good calculator, but understand what you are clicking.
http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-price-calculator/default.aspx

With MOSS you need CALs.  There is a Std CAL and then if you use MOSS Enterprise there is an add-on Enterprise CAL.

There is no one server topology.  Everything depends on what you plan to do with it, how many people, etc.  I generally don't like to use 2 server deployments (SP, SQL) even in non-production environments.  You are better off getting two smaller servers and separating the roles in most cases.

Before I made the jump from 2003 to 2007 for my first MOSS farm I probably spent 4-5 months planning it and taking it through scenarios.  I would encourage you to do some homework or bring in an outside expert.  Here is a good place to start if you want to read the docs:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261834.aspx

Comment: Im not sure how much i trust that calculator. I just typed in my latest project setup, and with all environments it ended on $10 mio -and that was even without the FAST license ;-)
Its the CAL's (especially Windows 2003 Server) that makes the price explode...

Comment: I don't know anyone that has had to pay list prices.  It certainly makes it look much more expensive than it is.  For companies that go with an Enterprise Agreement the CALs are normally included, or at least they were.  I think it is best to figure out what you need and then work with a vendor to license it.

Answer (score 4):

Mike made very good tips on what you should look for, the best approach is to find a Microsoft licensing partner in your region that can help you find the best licensing. There are many options for purchasing a license, e.g. if you are already under Enterprise Agreement with Microsoft, or if you are under Academic or some other special licensing program...

How do you know you need MOSS? If you need it, do you need Standard or Enterprise? 
It depends on your needs, and maybe you only need WSS. Check this article I wrote years ago. [Which SharePoint edition is right for me?](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2007/08/which-sharepoint-edition-is-right-for-you/)

Answer (score 4):

Some links:

Licensing:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/FX101865111033.aspx

Capacity planning:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262971.aspx

A Microsoft Partner is probably better able to assist on a budget estimate to implement SharePoint Server 2007.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

$119 per seat plus about $6000 per server for SharePoint 2010 Standard. Total cost to get it installed, configured and customized is typically 6-7X license fee according to Real Story Group.

The actual final cost depends on your Enterprise Agreement with Microsoft.